# Search EditText with my ListView doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, search, textedit

I want to create a ListView with an EditText as a search bar.
My ListView contains different kinds of custom cells (with only one String for each) so I use an ArrayAdapter, like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
MyAdapter adapter;

// Then...

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    String[] cellData;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        cellData = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View viewCE = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_cell, parent, false);
        ((TextView) viewCE.findViewById(R.id.text_my_cell)).setText(cellData[position]);
        view = viewCE;
        return view;
    }
}
```

This works pretty well.
Then I tried to mix it with my EditText field, so I declared it in my activity :

```
EditText inputSearch;
```

Then, added a filter on textChanged method :

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MyActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
});
```

The problem is the following. For example, if my list contains :

> APRIL DECEMBER JANUARY MAY

If I write "Y" in my search field I should only get `JANUARY` and `MAY`. 
But instead of this I get `APRIL` and `DECEMBER`.
In fact I get the exact amount of data (2 rows here), but starting from the beginning of the list.
What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally got the answer, need to use `adapter.getItem(position)` instead of `cellData[position]`.